# What is wrong with my implementation of importing csv into google sheets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, google-sheets, gspread

I am using gspread package in python, and I try to import a csv into a google spreadsheet, but I got an error.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Open a sheet from a spreadsheet
spreadsheet = client.open("BlogScraping")
print(spreadsheet.id)

res = requests.get("https://www.rithmschool.com/blog")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
articles = soup.find_all("article")

with open("blog_data.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["title", "link", "date"])

    for article in articles:
        title = article.find("a").get_text()
        url = article.find("a")["href"]
        date = article.find("time")["datetime"]
        csv_writer.writerow([title, url, date])

content = open('blog_data.csv', 'r').read()
client.import_csv(spreadsheet.id, content)
```

Here's the errors I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/scraping.py", line 32, in <module>
    client.import_csv(spreadsheet.id, content)
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 293, in import_csv
    self.request(
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 61, in request
    response = getattr(self.session, method)(
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in put
    return self.request('PUT', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 464, in request
    response = super(AuthorizedSession, self).request(
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/chrisrosana/PycharmProjects/webScrapeProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
    body = _encode(body, 'body')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 164, in _encode
    raise UnicodeEncodeError(
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 1980: Body ('–') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

I think I did the implementation correctly and my spreadsheet.id are correct also. I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error clearly states what actually went wrong. The content of the information you are sending contains a character which is not allowed. Have you tried the suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It's basically the content that I am sending contains a character that is not valid. It has something to do on utf-8 encoding. Adding content.encode('utf-8') will solve it.

So instead of

```
client.import_csv(spreadsheet.id, content)
```

do this:

```
client.import_csv(spreadsheet.id, data=content.encode('utf-8')
```

Thanks @Ludo21South